# how to insert negative value without minus symbol in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is that .. i want to insert negative value for eg: -456 into my DB with out the "-" minus symbol...

Comment: I do not understand the quesion. What's the problem with the minus sign?

Comment: you can have binary no and convert it to integer .

Comment: So a positive value?

Comment: ya .. i got the answer by the way ... INSERT INTO Table VALUES(ABS(-456))

Answer (score 0):

Use ABS function. That is

INSERT INTO Table VALUES(ABS(-456))

Answer (score 0):

:) DOnt know what is your perpose, but 
 Use two column, one for the value and another one for value type

---

### my_value (int) | value_type (tinyint, default: 1)  // consider 1 for + and o for -

### 456            | 0 //false or 0 for -456

456            | 1 // true or 1 for +456

.. :,)

Comment: Thank you ... @Jayanta Baishya

Answer (score 0):

A very bizarre question. But if still you want a solution for this then here it is -

**Solution 1**

As suggested by the others that you can use `ABS()` to remove your '-' sign from the data. BUT, I think in this case you will loose your valuable information.

**Solution 2**

You can use a Benchmark number according to your max negative value. According to your example, for -456, if it is max negative value then you can use 1000 as a Benchmark number. And in the logic just use

```
INSERT INTO Table VALUES( <YourData> + 1000 )
```

Hence, you will save 544 in your table. Like wise, in case of positive value, for example 456, data will be saved as 1456.

***Remember***, it will avoid you to create an extra column to save your number sign ('-' or '+'), BUT, in each DQL query (select *) you have to use your Benchmark number by calculating difference to get the correct data.

```
SELECT <YourStoredDataColumnName> - 1000 FROM Table
```